# How to add elements to listView from listener in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, interface

I would like to add elements to the listView in one fragment when the button in another fragment is pushed. I tried to figure it out by myself, but I couldn't find any solution.

These are my trials:

Code:

#### HistoryFragment.java - fragment in which I want a list view to be displayed

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    HistoryAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View history = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        ArrayList<ToSave> arrayOfData = new ArrayList<ToSave>();
        adapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), arrayOfData);
        listView = (ListView) history.findViewById (R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //ToSave toSave = new ToSave();
        //adapter.add(toSave);
        return history;

    }
}
```

#### HistoryAdapter.java - my listView adapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HistoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToSave>{

    public HistoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ToSave> records) {
        super(context, R.layout.history_item, records);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ToSave record = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        TextView tvStats = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStats);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvDate.setText(Integer.valueOf(record.numberDrinks).toString());
        tvStats.setText(Integer.valueOf(record.numberDrinks).toString());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

#### Interface which I created in the fragment from which I want to controll the list view:

```
OnFinishedParty mCallback;

    public interface OnFinishedParty {
        public void onFinishedParty();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {

            mCallback = (OnFinishedParty) activity;

        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFinishedParty");
        }
    }
```

#### Button listener in this Fragment

```
Button button5 = (Button) started.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onFinishedParty();
            }
        });
```

#### in MainActivity:

```
public void onFinishedParty() {
        ///What to put here??????
        ///Tried this but did not work:
        ToSave toSave = new ToSave();
        HistoryFragment.adapter.add(toSave);
        HistoryFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make in your fragment with `listView` some public method, for example with name `callBack()`.

Then in fragment with button take `FragmentManager` from activity, and use method `findFragmentById`. Then you can call your public method.

Sample from my code:

```
((MainMenuFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_menu_fragment)).notificationsReaded();
```

I hope it's clear enough :)

Comment: The problem is that I use fragments for a tabbed layout in my application dynamically and hence I have no Id for the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, how many fragments you have, and you're adding them manually in code, you should use file ids.xml in res/values , sample :

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="ambaja_view_reply_button" />
</resources>
```

Another option is to set them tags, and search by tag.

If not, maybe better solution is to use some views instead of tags (if you don't need to reuse them in another size layout for example for tablets, there is no need to use fragments..) and try also to add them tags or search in children of parent layout..